# Swift Timer that will not run again until a certain period of time

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

This is proving to be a challenge, I want a timer that triggers a pulse for a 10th of a second, then effectively blocks it from running again until at least 1 second has past.

This is the code for the pulse , but how can I block it from triggering again until 1 second has passed - could I put a timer within a timer?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
func pulseOn(on: Bool) {
    
    var pulseCount = 4
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.025, repeats: true)
    { timer in

         print("PulseCount: \(pulseCount)")

 
        pulseCount = pulseCount - 1


        if pulseCount < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 0.025 * 4 = 0.1, not 1 second. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: I think you could trigger another function inside this timer which sets a bool to false and runs a timer for a second the chnages the bool to true. Then only run your orginal timer when the bool is true?

Comment: I recommend to use `DispatchSourceTimer`. It's more flexible, more accurate and can be suspended and resumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When measuring time between two events, use `Date` and its `timeIntervalSince*` functions instead of a timer.

Use a property `lastPulse` to record the time of the last pulse and have a `Bool` property `pulseActive` that keeps track if a pulse in in progress.  Only run your function if 1 second has passed and a pulse is not active.

```
// time of last pulse
// seed lastPulse with distantPast so first pulse will always succeed
var lastPulse = Date.distantPast

// are we in the middle of running a pulse?
var pulseActive = false

func pulseOn(on: Bool) {
    guard !pulseActive && abs(lastPulse.timeIntervalSinceNow) >= 1 else { return }

    pulseActive = true

    // record the time of this pulse
    lastPulse = Date()

    var pulseCount = 4
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.025, repeats: true)
    { timer in

        print("PulseCount: \(pulseCount)")

        pulseCount = pulseCount - 1

        if pulseCount < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            pulseActive = false

            // If you want the time from last pulse end to be 1 second
            // then set lastPulse here instead
            //lastPulse = Date()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- Your `on:` `Bool` is unused.  I have left it there because I wanted to highlight just the new code.
- It wasn't clear if you wanted the 1 second interval to be from pulse start to pulse start or pulse end to pulse start.  If you want the pulse starts to be 1 second apart at least, then use the code as written.  If you want the next pulse to start at least one second after the previous pulse ended, then set `lastPulse = Date()` when the timer is invalidated.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what did it.

Comment: Please upvote the answers you found helpful and accept the one that was most helpful by checking the gray check mark to the left of the answer to turn it green.

Answer (score 1):

May something like this. add a bool;

```swift
var runPulse: Bool = false
```

orginal timer function:

```swift
func pulseOn(on: Bool) {

var pulseCount = 4
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.025, repeats: true)
{ timer in

    print("PulseCount: \(pulseCount)")

    secondCheck() //new funtion 
    pulseCount = pulseCount - 1


    if pulseCount < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()

    }
}

}
```

New function:

```swift
func pulseOn(on: Bool) {

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false)
{ timer in
      self.runPulse = true 
}

}
```

Then wherever you trigger the pulseOn func you can add an if statement.

```swift
if runPulse {
   pulseOn()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a crack at that tomorrow :)